# Woocommerce API - DELETE does not work

Tags: woocommerce

I'm doing a simple integration with the Woocommerce API. The "Create a customer" and "Retrieve a customer" commands worked correctly. But when trying to use the "Delete a customer" command, the API returns nothing, much less deletes the customer. See Postman's print (http://prnt.sc/ek8ed0)

I suspect that there are some server security rules that block the DELETE command, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue except that the DELETE acts like a GET, I delete customer id 4 and it returns the customer json. Have you made any progress on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it at my end. The host was rerouting DELETE request to GET requests. I edited my .htaccess and added:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Limit>
```

That fixed it for me.